# coffeescript sorting not right

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Here's my script:

```
alert("why isn't this sorted right? #{["6","7","2","11","10","9","4","5","3","8","1"].sort 
(a,b) -> +a < +b }")
```

You can try running it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert(%22why%20isn't%20this%20sorted%20right%3F%20%23%7B%5B%226%22%2C%227%22%2C%222%22%2C%2211%22%2C%2210%22%2C%229%22%2C%224%22%2C%225%22%2C%223%22%2C%228%22%2C%221%22%5D.sort%20%20(a%2Cb)%20-%3E%20%2Ba%20%3C%20%2Bb%20%7D%22)%0A).

The result will be:

> why isn't this sorted right? 9,6,8,11,10,7,5,4,3,2,1

My question is, why? I would expect the answer to be 11, 10, 9, 8, ....

It probably has something to do with strings vs numbers, but the "+" coerces the string to a number, and anyway, the result isn't a correct sort for even a string comparision. It just seems .. random.

Comment: 2 reasons, that's not how sort works.  sort expects the compare to return <0,0,or >0,. And secondly, your comparing strings not numbers,..

Comment: `alert("But this is sorted right? #{["6","7","2","11","10","9","4","5","3","8","1"].sort  (a,b) -> b - a }")`

Comment: @Keith please don't use the comments when you could have written an actual answer.

Comment: @Soviut  Your are of course correct,.. only problem is the silent Down-Voters.  You know the ones I mean, the ones who down vote, and can't even be bothered to give a reason.  So because of this I'm often reluctant to give an answer.  Shame really I know, maybe it's something Stack Overflow Dev's  can look into.  I can even see this question has been down voted, Why?, (again no reasons given).  The OP had even created an example for people to look at,.  Are we saying even asking questions on SO is now wrong.

Comment: @keith - I'm not comparing strings - that's what the "+" operator does. Also, why the downvote? It was a reasonable question, the "<" operator works in like that in lots of other languages.

Comment: @Rob, it wasn't me who down voted you, in fact the comment before yours is me complaining about this practice, and indeed your question was a totally valid one.  I must admit never noticed the '+'s..

Comment: Sorry @keith - I conflated two comments in one. I also wanted to thank you for pointing out the problem.

Comment: @Rob  no problem easy done, anyway I'll counter balance the invalid down-vote you got.

Comment: @Keith if your answer was well written it won't get downvotes. Not posting answers for fear of downvotes is a ridiculous practice since downvoting reduces the voter's rep too. You basically just missed out on 35-45 rep.

Comment: @Soviut It's maybe just me, but when I get down-votes, especially when no reason given, I find it insulting.  And I'm not really bothered too much about rep (!=rep tart).. I think I'll live with it.  Personally I think SO needs to implement a forced reason for down-voting.  It could even stay anonymous.  Down voting, without a reason is just Rude, (with a capital R).. :)

Comment: @Keith don't take them as insults, they're votes. People have reasons but no election ever asked people to explain why they voted for a candidate on a ballot. After a few thousand rep you won't even notice when they occur. Gaming the system by using comments won't help, you just annoy admins.

Comment: @Soviut  I'll try and take on board what you have said, if you look at my profile you can see I've only been a member for 25 days.  From a new-comers POV I can't see them as anything other than an insult, not sure you can compare to an election voting system, as these votes are saying  `This answer is not useful` (it say's this on the hint).  In my spare time I coach under 10's football, if one of the parents came up to me and said `your coaching is not useful` , I would go home feeling rather low.  Like you say though, I'll maybe ignore them, and see how I go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Keith [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076207/coffeescript-sorting-not-right/40079291#comment67425675_40076207), the issue isn't with Coffeescript, but with a misuse of the comparator function, which `Array::sort` accepts.

```coffee
alert(
  "In order to work, a comparator must return -1, 1 or 0 #{
    ["6","7","2","11","10","9","4","5","3","8","1"].sort(
      (a, b) -> +b - +a
   )}"
 )
```

`Array.prototoype.sort` [documentation](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort).
Run it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert(%0A%20%20%22In%20order%20to%20work%2C%20a%20comparator%20must%20return%20-1%2C%201%20or%200%3A%20%23%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%226%22%2C%227%22%2C%222%22%2C%2211%22%2C%2210%22%2C%229%22%2C%224%22%2C%225%22%2C%223%22%2C%228%22%2C%221%22%5D.sort(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(a%2Cb%2C%20c%20%3D%20%2Ba%2C%20d%20%3D%20%2Bb)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20c%20%3C%20d%20then%20-1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20c%20%3E%20d%20then%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%200%0A%20%20%20)%7D%22%0A%20)).